# Partly colored row in tabularx

Tags: tabularx

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Example}
    \begin{tabularx}{0.4\textwidth}{lll}
        \hline
        \rowcolor{yellow}
        A & C & E... \\
        B & D & F...... \\
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

And the output is like this:
[image]

Why the yellow row color is not filling the entire row, but only the part which has some text in it ?

Thank you

Comment: At least one of the columns should employ the `X` column type.

Answer (score 2):

The `tabularx` package provides the `X` column type. If you want the `tabularx` environment to take up the specified width, at least one of the columns must employ the `X` column type (or a column type that's derived from `X`).

For instance:

```
\begin{tabularx}{0.4\textwidth}{XXX}
```

will ensure that the three columns are equally wide.